# Angular - Conditional formatting a label with ngIf and ngFor using regex and css

Tags: css, regex, angular, ngfor, angular-ng-if

I want to conditionnally color some labels from data I get from a web service. The web service works fine and the data gets saved to an array b.

For example, 
if the label contains "blue", color it blue,
if the label contains "red", color it red
etc.
I'll have max 6 conditions.

```
  <div class="centered">
        <h2>List of labels </h2>
                <label *ngFor="let a of b">  
                    {{a.x}}  
                  </label>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've found out the trick

The HTML

```
<div class="centered">
        <h2>List of labels </h2>
                <label *ngFor="let a of b" [ngStyle]=" {color:findColor(a.x)}">

                    {{a.x}}  
                  </label>
    </div>
```

The typescript

```
public findColor(a: string): string {

      var blue = a.match(/blue/);
      var red = a.match(/red/);
      if(red) {
        return "#ff0000";
      }
      if(blue) {
        return "#0000ff";
      }
      return null;
    }
```

Thanks all for your help. Works fine with regex :)

Answer (score 1):

What you need is `ngStyle`.

```
<div class="centered">
        <h2>List of labels </h2>
        <label *ngFor="let a of b" [ngStyle]="{color: a.color}">  
           {{a.x}}  
        </label>
</div>
```

Or ask your server to provide classNames and use `[ngClass]`

Comment: Thanks Arif. The thing is that the data is retrieved from a web service which does not provide a property. It returns string. So I need to regex this string on the ngfor to check if it contains blue or red or green etc and color it blue or red or green etc.

Comment: What this string looks like? Can you give an example value?  I might help

Answer (score 0):

Just add a function to your Component, which returns any color.

```
        <h2>List of labels </h2>
        <label *ngFor="let a of listA" [ngStyle]="{color: findColor(a)}">  
           {{a}}  
        </label>
```

Example:

```
listA: string[] = ['I am red.', 'I am blue.', 'I am normal.']

  findColor(a: string): string {
    if(a.includes('red')) {
      return "#ff0000";
    }
    if(a.includes('blue')) {
      return "#0000ff";
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Hello MoxxiManagarm, I'm getting this :   includes is not a function

Comment: For me it works perfectly. Please google the error message.

Comment: Yes, for you it will work as you are using an array. I want to use Regex as I've said from the beginning.

Comment: The includes was just an example from me since I don't know what your conditions are. You maybe want to change a for you, since a is a string in my example. You also need to adjust your conditions. The main point of my example is to use a string returning function, which includes the conditions.